# Помогите понять на что ругается интерпретатор? Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: python

Ругается на последнюю круглую скобку после буквы t в строке объявления функции: `def bezierslopeatt(((bx0,by0),(bx1,by1),(bx2,by2),(bx3,by3)),t):`

```
def bezierslopeatt(((bx0,by0),(bx1,by1),(bx2,by2),(bx3,by3)),t):
    ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy,x0,y0=bezmisc.bezierparameterize(((bx0,by0),(bx1,by1),(bx2,by2),(bx3,by3)))
    dx=3*ax*(t**2)+2*bx*t+cx
    dy=3*ay*(t**2)+2*by*t+cy
    if dx==dy==0 : 
        dx = 6*ax*t+2*bx
        dy = 6*ay*t+2*by
        if dx==dy==0 : 
            dx = 6*ax
            dy = 6*ay
            if dx==dy==0 : 
                print_("Slope error x = %s*t^3+%s*t^2+%s*t+%s, y = %s*t^3+%s*t^2+%s*t+%s,  t = %s, dx==dy==0" % (ax,bx,cx,dx,ay,by,cy,dy,t))
                print_(((bx0,by0),(bx1,by1),(bx2,by2),(bx3,by3)))
                dx, dy = 1, 1
                
    return dx,dy
```

Answer (score 0):

у меня PyCharm говорит:

```
  File "D:\lessons\python\test2.py", line 1
    def bezierslopeatt(((bx0, by0), (bx1, by1), (bx2, by2), (bx3, by3)), t):
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

вам надо задавать параметры через запятую, а не в скобках

если вы хотите задать кортеж, то все равно задаете его через запятую, а обращаетесь уже по индексу внутри функции:

```
def func(obj, t):
    sub_obj0 = obj[0]
    sub_sub_sub_obj0 = sub_obj0[0]
```